# Linking object files to executable not working

Tags: c++, compilation, linker-errors, dlib, object-files

I am trying to compile an example from dlib.net using g++. I find that directly compiling the example into an executable works fine using:

```sh
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/lib /usr/lib/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 optimization_ex.cpp -o optimiation_ex
```

But when I compile the source into object files first (1) and link later (2),

1. ```sh
   g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/lib -c /usr/lib/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 -o /usr/lib/dlib/all/source.o
   g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/lib -c optimization_ex.cpp -lpthread -lX11 -o optimization_ex.o
   ```
2. ```sh
   g++ /usr/lib/dlib/all/source.o optimization_ex.o -o optimization_ex
   ```

Then the executable cannot be compiled and g++ complains about undefined references.

What is going on behind this behavior? And how can I link the executable from the object files?

Comment: You give *linker flags* when compiling the source files, and none when you're actually linking the object files.

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks! I will mark your comment as an answer if you make an answer from it.